# Something like pubsubhubbub that does not depend on google app engine

Tags: python, rss, feed, websub, atom-feed

I am looking for something like [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) that does not depend on google app engine to run.

What I need is a tool that can track for me a big very large number of rss or atom feeds and issue events when they are updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pubsubhubbub is a protocol, and, as such, does not depend on app engine.  For example, [superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) is another implementation of this protocol (I believe it's free for the first 1000 feeds, then something like 50 dollars a month for the next 1000 feeds, then decreasing gradually for even larger number of feeds).

Comment: thanks, but pubsubhubbub comes with a default implementation, doesn't it? or at least it is a project in google code, so it must be something that can actually be run....

Comment: Flybywire : yes there is a default OSS hub you can find on GAE, but it doesn't do polling, which means it will only work for the feeds which are using PubSubHubbub on their end.

Comment: @Julien, right -- pubsubhubbub _is_ "opt-in" at both ends, i.e., both the servers (feeds) and the clients (readers or more typically aggregators) must speak to it. I believe that `superfeedr` obviates this by adding (to the pubsubhubbub protocol itself) a "poll the servers" part for feeds that _don't_ explicitly sign up to give it info in pubsubhubbub ways, but that's just my impression (haven't seen their sources!). The reference implementation (for GAE) _does_ "depend on GAE" (or appscale or typhoonae of course;-), of course, and doesn't poll (does just the pubsubhubbub protocol itself).

Comment: So actually, the default hub (GAE) acts as the protocols specifies : it polls upon pings. The only difference for superfeedr is that we can poll even when there are no pings.

Comment: @Julien, thanks for clarifying the detail! (I don't think of "poll upon ping" as _poll_ -- **polling**, to me, means a stream of periodical unprompted "are we there yet?" questions, while the exchqnge "we're there!" / "where?" is not a _poll_, to my way of thinking, but rather more reminiscent of an observable/observer design pattern;-).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://git.participatoryculture.org/djpubsubhubbub/) is Django library implementing this protocol.